# IdentityServer4 Login user validate in Client application using OpenID Connect Events

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm developing .NET core(2.2) application. we are using IdentityServer4 for user login. I want to validate the login user after user login from Identity Server application. we are using common Identity Server for multiple application. So I should validate in client application only.

I want to validate in OpenID Connect events like.

For example,

[image]

Is there any possible to do like this?.

Comment: A better approach is to do this validation of the user in the authorization handler in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: If I can use authorization handler user able to keep login session. my scenario is if login user period expired. user could not allow to login. I should throw exception message like your login period time expired.

Comment: With OpenID Connect you can configure so you are redirected back to identityServer or a "not logged in" error page when the cookie/user-session expires.

Comment: I want to do like if login user period expired. i have to throw CustomError page and also i have to clear user login session and cookie.

Comment: You have several things that can expire, the local cookie session, the access token and the refresh token, you also have a cookie session with IdentityServer.

Comment: my Scenario, ABC is company. One of the employee have on login. that employee working in one year contract. So that employee have start and end date. Once the employee contract end. I should not allow to login that employee. I want to show Custom Message like "Your contract has been expired".

Comment: You have multiple option. One option is to add a "UserExpire" claim in the user profile and check that claim when you authorize the user on each request. Then you refresh the local "user" using the refresh token to get new claim data into the client on a regular basis. Alternatively, you use refresh token and in IdentityServer check if the user has expired or is disabled each time you refresh the access token.

Comment: The problem, I did not check in this validation in Identity Server. It is common Identity Server for multiple web app. I want to do this in web app only

Comment: Even, i can't able to add Claim also

Comment: if user period expired. Is there any option to user logout and redirect to custom message page in Authorization handler?.

Comment: First of all , you need to separate the involvement of AddOpenIDConnect and AddCookie. AdDOpenIDConnect is mainly only involved when the user is first logging in. Then it passes over the user to the cookie handler , it will then create the session cookie and saves the user/tokens in that cookie. The cookie handler is then the only one involved in all the requests after that. Until someone challengs the user, and then the OpenIDConnect is involved again.

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, that's not working in my scenario.

Comment: its hard to give a more specific answer without having access to the big picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the users using the event handlers, but a better solution is to do that part in the authorization handler in ASP.NET Core. All this is built into ASP.NET Core and allows you to create pretty complex authorization scenarios using the policy based authorization model built in.

You can read more about that here: [Policy-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

It is also important to separate the authentication and authorization and use this architecture as it is meant to be used in ASP.NET Core, as this picture shows:

[image]